# Происхождение слова "хана"

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Хана - это просторечно-жаргонное слово со смыслом "конец", "крышка".
У меня есть ощущение, что это слово тюркского происхождения (может, из-за ударения на последний слог), но интересно было бы узнать точно, откуда это слово взялось в русском языке? И насколько оно вообще жаргонное или сленговое?

Comment: Слово "хана" в просторечии употребляется и в смысле "смерть". Например: "Ну всё, хана тебе(смерть тебе)!"

Comment: Все-таки, тут не обязательно в значении "смерть". Скорее, просто: "Теперь тебе плохо придется".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тюркская версия (хана - постоялый двор или иное помещение - чайхана) не наводит на близкий смысл.

На санскрите (в латинской записи hanana, иногда так трактуют и русское "хана") это убийство или избиение (уже что-то более близкое).

Ещё ссылаются на сибирский диалектный глагол "хануть" (пропасть, исчезнуть) - видимо, это родственно с "кануть".

Comment: Да, вероятнее всего это санскритское "хан" - убивать, бить и "ханти" - убивает. Отсюда английское hunter -охотник и hunt - охотиться, а охота - это убийство и есть. Возможно, слово "хана"  вышло из охотничьей среды и попало в английский от нас.

Comment: Вот это да! Казалось бы такое более чем просторечное слово, а происхождение еще из санскрита.

Comment: Всё дело в том, что сейчас немало фактов говорит о том, что санскрит может являться наследником праславянского, ведь на нём не говорят и не говорили народы. Это язык жрецов, а вот как и почему они стали пользоваться именно этим языком достоверно не знают даже в Индии, хотя некоторые легенды есть.

Comment: Это я  к тому, что не разделяю русский и санскрит и не пытаюсь расставлять приоритеты о том, какой  древнее. Просто считаю, что когда-то был один язык и многие слова ходят по кругу.

Answer (score 1):

Тюркская версия мне кажется верной, тем более, что тюркское хан означает не только "царь" , но в диалектном "кан"-"кровь".

Но есть и другая версия: http://www.liveinternet.ru/users/4845765/post312070195   
Хана – конец. חנה – ивр. хана – делать остановку в пути, привал. Это корень очень широко распространен в иврите (ханая, - автостоянка, ханут – склад, магазин).

Comment: Толковый словарь русского сленга В. С. Елистратова указывает только, что слово заимствовано из тюркских языков, вероятнее всего, 
через уголовный жаргон. Последнее очень похоже на правду, поскольку слово не зафиксировано в словарях, изданных ранее второй половины 20 века.

Comment: Из юмористического словаря: "Чайхана - неурожай чая"))))

Answer (score -1):

Весьма прозаично происхождение и слова поХЕРить и ХЕР. Рязаньские, Владимирские,.. ушкуйники часто ходили разбойничьими походами на поселения Волжско-Камской Булгарии! Грабили, насиловали чувашских женщин и ДЕВУШЕК! Вот девушка на чувашском языке и есть ХĔР! Собираясь в очередную вылазку меж собой с вожделением и говорили "пошли на ХЕР" – то есть: пошли по девкам(бабам).
   Кстати, УШКУЙНИК тоже чувашского происхождения от УШКĂН – ватага, группа!
Не в тех словарях ищете! Читайте Ашмарина, русского тюрколога, который писал: "русский язык своим происхождением и развитием обязан языку чувашскому"!